# Who was the first Russian woman to live in Petropavlovsk-Kamchatsky?

Tags: russia, colonization, ethnicity, gender

Petropavlovsk-Kamchatsky is a port city on the Pacific Ocean. The indigenes in its location were Itelmen (Kamchadals). Today its population was dominated by ethnic Russians, but in the mid-18th century only men arrived from Russia, such as Cossacks, soldiers, and monks. If any of the Russian men had children there, it was with women of native or mixed heritage.

Petropavlovsk wasn't an *ostrog*, but the place was more of an army outpost than a town. There weren't enough townspeople to support a church [Витер: *Петропавловск (историческая справка)*], as there were barely any families in town [Krusenstern, *Voyage Autour Du Monde*, II:519]. By 1804 two dozen women of unspecified ethnicity were living in Petropavlovsk. [Moessner: *The First Russian Voyage Around the World*, pp. 325].

Who was the first ethnically Russian woman to live in Petropavlovsk?